# Launch Google Play Store for Developer

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to launch "Developer apps" from my Android app with this code:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:VenturezLab"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Play Store starts, but says, that no apps found. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that what you're pointing to isn't a package name.

Use `market://search?q=pub:VenturezLab` instead.

Comment: Since that is the correct way of searching for it, it would seem that Google Play is filtering the apps to target your phone. Are you certain that the phone pulling up the listing matches your speedcam app requirements?

Comment: Hm, didn't think about it. It's set-top box ICS device, I'll check it when'll be on the work.